# Why doesn't the Application finish?

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea, gradle

I run this main class with Gradle plugin `application` and task `run` from IntelliJ. I can run it and debug it, but the programm don't finish. That means, that it looks in IntelliJ that the programm still runs but I see in debug mode, that it leaves the main() method.

What can be the reason?

Code:

```
public class HibernateTest {

    public static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("TEST");
        EntityManager entityManager;
        try {
            setUp();

            entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            entityManager.persist( new Person( "Jim" ) );
            entityManager.persist( new Person( "Tim") );
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            entityManager.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }

        System.out.println("Finished");
    }

    protected static void setUp() throws Exception {
        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "vwg.vw.hrit.HibernateTest" );
    }
}
```

IntelliJ Screen:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write:

```
entityManagerFactory.close();
```

This will make your entityManager be considered closed as well:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html#close--

Answer (score 0):

There is still a non daemon thread running.

Attach to the running process with jstack to take a thread dump or ask your IDE to do so.